# Using t() in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, localization, drupal-7

I've searched how to do it a week, but haven't success and it's been a bottleneck in the work so, I decided to ask.

I put `<h3><?php print t("strings translation"); ?></h3>` in page.tpl.php and flush all caches and reload every languages available in the site.

And then I try to search for the string in /admin/config/regional/translate/i18n_string the options available are Fields, Node types, Menu, Taxonomy, Blocks.

But then I can't find the "strings translation" in /admin/config/regional/translate/translate.

I have read in drupal.org documentation but it seems like I'm missing something.

Could you please advice how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you missing echo in your code?

```
 <h3><?php echo t("strings translation"); ?></h3>
```

I am not clear what are you looking for. But [Stringoverrides modeule](http://drupal.org/project/stringoverrides) may solve your problem. It can translate any string across the project. But, if the string is inside t() function.

Comment: I forgot, I use print
<h3><?php print t("strings translation"); ?></h3>
is it different?

Comment: No its the same. Are you still getting issue?

Comment: The string doesn't appear in "translate" page after I search in "strings". I don't know what i missed :(

Comment: I am not clear what are you looking for. But https://www.drupal.org/project/stringoverrides may solve your problem. It can translate any string across the project. But, if the string is inside t() function.

Comment: The module is great. It worked perfectly. Thank you very much :D

Comment: actually, i tried. but it says "require 15 reputation". I'll try again later :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the way:
1) Drupal should know that a string is 'not translated'. To make it aware of this, you need to visit the page having the string and change the language. Once you do, Drupal will be aware of all those strings on the page which are not translated to the language selected currently.
2) Go to translate page, search for the string, it should now appear there